# iOS provisioning - will it break my existing app's APNs on the app store if I create a Adhoc provision?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store, apple-push-notifications

I currently have an app in the app store and lost my provisioning profile that had Ad-hoc as its distribution method.

I need to test the production APNs on a device before I push out the app but cant do that with the current provision's method set to distribution.
Will it break anything already in the app store if I set the method to adhoc, download that then set the method back to distribution and release/code sign with that for app store submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your basic question is can you change the provisioning profile for an app in the app store when you resubmit the app, the answer is YES!

The only thing that is important in the provisioning profile is the bundle id. Once you create an app in iTunesConnect, the bundle ID can never change. So, the exact copy of the provisioning profile submitted with an app to the app store makes no difference, as long as it contains the right bundle id and it uses an "app store" distribution method.